# Whats the purpose of inputted address inside []?

Tags: java, arraylist

Can i ask whats the meaning of the input "52" on [], because if i delete the 52 the program wont run.

```java
ArrayList<String> playerCard[]= new ArrayList[52];
```

Comment: [Arrays trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 0):

The 52 tells the compiler how large the array is.

Comment: but sir even the output is more than 52, its still running.

Comment: Since you haven't put your code here, we can't know this. However, there are 52 cards in a normal deck of card.